# Hibernate - NonUniqueObjectException

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I use JPA/Hibernate with Spring transaction management in my application.
There is a InspectionEntity which has a one-to-many relation with InspectionDetailEntity.
The PKs for both the entity's are created by an insert trigger in the database. The PK values when I try to save is the default 0 value.
I add the InspectionDetailEntity to the InspectionEntity by calling addInspectionDetail() and then save the InspectionEntity - `entityManager.persist(inspection);`
What I expect is the Inspection to be saved with all the InspectionDetail's.
But this results in a 
**org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.xyz.entity.InspectionDetailEntity#0].**
I also tried setting the Set directly into the  InspectionEntity  (without using the addInspectionDetail() ). This also results in the same error. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_inspection")
public class InspectionEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "inspection_id")
    private Integer inspectionId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "inspectionDetailId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "inspection_id", insertable = true, updatable = true)
    private Set<InspectionDetailEntity> inspectionDetails;

    /**
     * Adds a inspectionDetailEntity to the set of inspectionDetails
     * @param inspectionDetailEntity
     */
    public void addInspectionDetail(InspectionDetailEntity inspectionDetailEntity) {
        if(inspectionDetails == null)
            inspectionDetails = new HashSet<InspectionDetailEntity>();
        inspectionDetailEntity.setInspection(this);
        inspectionDetails.add(inspectionDetailEntity);
    }
    //setter and getters
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_inspection_dtl")
public class InspectionDetailEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "inspection_dtl_id")
    private Integer inspectionDetailId;

    @Column(name = "inspection_id")
    private Integer inspectionId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="inspection_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private InspectionEntity inspection;


    //setters and getters 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set id to 0 before you save it. Leave it as null. If value is set Hibernate will assume that object is already in the database and attempt to update it.

And you probably ending up with multiple objects with the same id (0).

---

Update

As I think about it, you are, probably, forced to set id to some value because you don't have id generator and Hibernate expects you to provide value for id. However, there is nothing in Hibernate that would update ids on your objects after insert. So you end up with multiple objects in session with id 0.

I am not sure what would be good solution for this situation. Most likely you will need to write custom id generator. But in case of sequences, for example, it requires extra call to the database. May be you should consider id assignment other than trigger?

Comment: I explicitly set the inspectionDetailId as null, and tried to save. But now I get a `org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.xyz.entity.InspectionDetailEntity`

Comment: @joji That's exactly my point. Since you didn't specify id generator, Hibernate expects you to provide id. But it must be real id not 0 for every object. So you have a problem with your trigger id assignment. Check docs, there may be some suitable generator for your use case

Comment: I removed the DB insert trigger and instead used a DB sequence( @SequenceGenerator) on my entity PK attribute. I know its not a very impressive solution, since extra calls are made to get the next sequence value for each child object. Maybe at a later point of time I would go for a custom id generator like seqhilo.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing either

`inspectionDetailEntity.setInspection(this);`

or

```
inspectionDetails.add(inspectionDetailEntity);
```

I don't think you need both.

It might be worth considering a unidirection relationship between your child and parent